# Signing data is throwing exception for RSA SHA512 algo with key size as 512 and 1024

Tags: c#, .net-core, rsa, sha, sha512

Signing data using RSA key with below dotnet function is throwing exception :

```
var rsa = RSA.Create();

rsa.SignData(data, hashAlgorithm, padding);
```

Exception:

> "The parameter is incorrect."

**Table with more combinations:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr3wo.png)

Comment: The key size of RSA/SHA-512 keys MUST NOT be less than 1024 bits and
   MUST NOT be more than 4096 bits.  See Para 2.2 : https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5702

Comment: This results from a condition of PSS (RFC8017, 9.1.1, [Def. of emBits](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-9.1.1)), according to which the key/modulus size must be at least the sum of the salt and hash size plus 9 bits. The default salt size is identical to the hash size (RFC8017, [A.2.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.2.3)), resulting in the minimum key sizes 1024/1024/2048 bits for SHA256/384/512 in accordance with your test. This is explained in more detail [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/77477).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please help me to calculate the ranges of key sizes for SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512. As now, found a new case where SHA256 and SHA384 not working with keysize of 512.

Comment: Please help on keysizes for PKCS1 and PSS padding as well.